# Angular adds my form fields to URL on cancellation

Tags: angular

I have an Angular form that built with the ngForm object:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="sendForm()" #f="ngForm">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fEmail">Your E-Mail address</label>
    <input type="text" id="fEmail" class="form-control" name="email"
           required ngModel #fEmail="ngModel" />
    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="fEmail.touched && !fEmail.valid">
      Please Provide a Valid E-mail Address.
    </span>
  </div>

   (rest of form fields omitted)

  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!f.valid" type="submit">
      Send Message
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/">
      Cancel
    </button>
  </div>

</form>
```

When I click the **Cancel** button, the router goes to the home page "/" as expected but it adds the form fields as parameters to the URL:

```
http://localhost:4200/?email=derp@derp.com&name=whome
```

Two questions:

1. Why is this behavior implemented and in what situations would it be useful?
2. How do I stop it from doing that?   I have code that watches the URL and I have to work around this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you should specify the button type.

### Why is this behavior implemented and in what situations would it be useful?

When you haven't specified the button type inside an angular form, angular detects it as a kind of submit button. So on cancel it also sends back all the form fields with the request.
In most cases this functionality wont be needed because, we write our own custom cancel function with click events right? but if you want a separate route for the cancel function to work you can make use of this feature.

### How do I stop it from doing that?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/">
          Cancel
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the type attribute to button:

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" routerLink="/">
      Cancel
    </button>
```

By default it will be used as a submit button.